# Get current fragment displayed in FragmentContainerView from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Im using Navigation Component which navigates between fragments using `findNavController().navigate()`. I want to retrieve the currently displayed fragment in `FragmentContainerView` from `MainActivity` as I want to modify the "Edit" button `setOnClickListener` function to perform "Save" function (I already know how to change the text from Edit to Save) where it checks currently displayed fragment and change the `setOnClickListener` function accordingly. So in that particular fragment, it will perform "Save" function. But how do I get the currently displayed fragment from `MainActivity`?

I saw alot other solution but they are all using `FragmentTransaction` or they just show the code which get the current Fragment but they didn't show in which part of `MainActivity` will initiate the code which gets the current Fragment. Any help? Im using Kotlin.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "how do you know what the current fragment is as I want to change my activity's UI based on what fragment I am on?" or are you saying you actually what to access the fragment itself to call methods on it, etc.? Please explain how your edit/save button is related to your activity and fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Im thinking of doing a if-else statement where it checks the current fragment, `if(editFragment), button.setOnClickListener{code for edit}, else if(saveFragment), button.setOnClickListener(code for save)` So i need to know the Fragment, in my Activity in order to perform this. Or is there any other way to achieve this? As I implement only a single Activity and the "Edit/Save" is in the Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `OnDestinationChangedListener` to the `NavController` inside you `MainActivity`

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.your_savable_fragment) {
       button.text = "Save"
       //....
   }
   if(destination.id == R.id.your_editable_fragment) {
       button.text = "Edit"
       //....
   }
}
```